Hausman Test Reults Report
I've been working on a research project using a multi-level regression model, and I'm currently figuring out how to present the Hausman test results. I've seen some papers where authors mention doing the test but don't include the numbers, just saying that the random effects model was more appropriate.
I wonder if it's standard practice to report the Hausman test results in the manuscript separately for each model. I know that if the test isn't significant (p > 0.05), it means the random effects model is more suitable. But I'm curious if it's common to also report the test value and other statistical details, like the chi-square value, to back up this conclusion. I have eight models btw

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Reporting the quantitative evidence on which some "final conclusion" like "model A is more appropriate than model B" is based, should always be done.
Readers should have the opportunity, if they want to, to form an opinion by themselves, and not rely on the statements made by the authors.
This is not about "distrust", or about detecting mistakes, but is due to the fact that the same quantitative evidence may be interpreted differently by different people.
As regards statistical tests, one should at least report the statistic being computed (since the statistic being computed may take different computational forms), the distribution on which the test is based (e.g. standard Normal, or chi-square with 3 degrees of freedom, etc), and the value of the statistic that was obtained.
In simpler $t$-tests the standard error should be reported, while a $p$-value is helpful to the reader. Drop the "significance" asterisks.
I know that we do not always see these in published papers, but we should.
